# Web Socket handshake error in Docker

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, docker, websocket

I use `Python 3.5`, `Flask` and `Meinheld` web socket middleware to serve sockets. Here is server side code sample:

```
@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    ws = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    while True:
        m = ws.wait()
        if m is None:
            break
        ws.send(m)

    return ""
```

Client side code sample:

```
var s = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4567/chat");
```

However, everything works properly while I run it in local mode, but when i add this into docker container i always get error like this:

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4567/chat' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500**

It does not matter where docker container is run, on remote server or local environment, the error is always the same. All necessary ports are exposed.

Comment: can you share more information, like your dockerfile and the command you run the container with. it would help get a better understanding as your problem seems to be with docker not the python app.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29Xm3M - Here is everything you want

Comment: You can embed these scripts to your answer...

Comment: It will not help you, server - is common Flask application with websockets middleware and client - uses simple javascript websocket class.

Comment: you can run in bash mode and try run the app inside docker manually whilst reading the logs to see more verbose output